# How to display Special Characters in J2ME

Tags: java-me, character-encoding, special-characters

I am working on a mobile app. I am confused about  how to insert special characters in J2ME (Integration Symbols,Subscript,Superscript)

Kindly replay
Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this in the textbox:-

```
TextBox mTextBox = new TextBox("Enter special charater:--", "", 25, TextField.ANY);
```

Comment: Thank for the answer Shweta. But You Misunderstood my Question . I have to display the  Special characters to the user . I dont have to read it from user.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer as well